# Group results by ID and show multiple records in one row on MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

In my database I have the tables bellow:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM ultrasound_results;
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
| result_id | architecture_id | value  |
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
|        29 |               1 |   0.00 |
|        29 |               2 |  90.00 |
|        29 |               3 |  14.14 |
|        30 |               1 |   0.00 |
|        30 |               2 |  90.00 |
|        30 |               3 |  14.14 |
|        31 |               1 |   0.00 |
|        31 |               2 |  90.00 |
|        31 |               3 |  14.14 |
|        32 |               1 |  21.49 |
|        32 |               2 |  20.72 |
|        32 |               3 |  63.69 |
|       333 |               1 |  41.34 |
|       333 |               2 |  22.71 |
|       333 |               3 | 112.13 |
+-----------+-----------------+--------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM muscle_achitectures;
+----+------------------+
| id | name             |
+----+------------------+
|  3 | Fascicle Length  |
|  1 | Muscle Thickness |
|  2 | Pennation Angle  |
+----+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, by using the query bellow:

```
SELECT ur.result_id, ma.name, ur.value 
FROM ultrasound_results ur 
    INNER JOiN muscle_achitectures ma 
        ON ur.architecture_id=ma.id 
ORDER BY ur.result_id
```

I get this output:

```
+-----------+------------------+--------+
| result_id | name             | value  |
+-----------+------------------+--------+
|        29 | Fascicle Length  |  14.14 |
|        29 | Muscle Thickness |   0.00 |
|        29 | Pennation Angle  |  90.00 |
|        30 | Pennation Angle  |  90.00 |
|        30 | Fascicle Length  |  14.14 |
|        30 | Muscle Thickness |   0.00 |
|        31 | Muscle Thickness |   0.00 |
|        31 | Pennation Angle  |  90.00 |
|        31 | Fascicle Length  |  14.14 |
|        32 | Muscle Thickness |  21.49 |
|        32 | Pennation Angle  |  20.72 |
|        32 | Fascicle Length  |  63.69 |
|       333 | Pennation Angle  |  22.71 |
|       333 | Fascicle Length  | 112.13 |
|       333 | Muscle Thickness |  41.34 |
+-----------+------------------+--------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I really what to do is write an SQL query that will give an output like this:

```
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| result_id | Fascicle Length  | Muscle Thickness  |  Pennation Angle  |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|        29 | 14.14            |  0.00             |    90.00          |
|        30 | 14.14            |  0.00             |    90.00          |    
|        31 | 14.14            |  0.00             |    90.00          |
|        32 | 63.69            |  21.49            |    20.72          |
|       333 | 112.13           |  41.34            |    22.71          |
+-----------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have read few things about PIVOT, but I am not sure how can I do that and if pivot is what I need. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the number of *muscle_achitectures* available at design time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With group by result_id and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  ur.result_id, 
  max(case ma.name when 'Fascicle Length' then ur.value end) `Fascicle Length`, 
  max(case ma.name when 'Muscle Thickness' then ur.value end) `Muscle Thickness`,
  max(case ma.name when 'Pennation Angle' then ur.value end) `Pennation Angle`
FROM ultrasound_results ur INNER JOiN muscle_achitectures ma 
ON ur.architecture_id=ma.id 
GROUP BY ur.result_id
ORDER BY ur.result_id
```

Comment: Great !! it does exactly what I need. But, what if the names inside `muscle_achitectures` is changing dynamically ? I don't want to go into the code and change the query every time that `muscle_achitectures`  is been updated

Comment: Then you will need dynamic sql.

Comment: Using SQL varialbles ? Is there a way to write `max(case ma.name when 'Fascicle Length' then ur.value end) 'Fascicle Length',` in something as a loop ?

Comment: That's interesting!! I understand the logic. I need to adjust it into my case, but I am sure that it will work. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Mysql have not features for pivot but if you have a limited  there are some techniques  one of this i based on join on the same table filter by the different values

```
    SELECT ur1.result_id
        , ur1.value `Fascicle Length`
        , ur2.value `Muscle Thickness`
        , ur3.value `Pennation Angle`   
    FROM ultrasound_results ur1 
    INNER join ultrasound_results ur2 on ur1.result_id = ur2.result_id 
        and ur2.architecture_id = 2 
    INNER join ultrasound_results ur3 on ur1.result_id = ur3.result_id 
        and ur2.architecture_id = 3 
    whene ur1.architecture_id = 1 
    ORDER BY ur.result_id
```